How to set QoS setting and publisher to publish stereo images in sync?
I am creating a ROS 2 driver for two OAK FFC OV9282 M12 cameras connected to OAK FFC 3P board. I am synchronizing images by using Luxonis DepthAI library and by giving the same timestamp before publishing images next to each other in two lines of code.When I use SLAM algorithms like RTABMAP and Isaac ROS cuVSLAM, I get messages that suggest jitter issues or synchronization issues.
First let me share the QoS profile I am using:
rmw_qos_profile_t custom_qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_default;
    custom_qos_profile.history = RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST;
    custom_qos_profile.depth = 1; // Keep only the last message
    custom_qos_profile.reliability = RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT;
    custom_qos_profile.durability = RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_VOLATILE;
    custom_qos_profile.deadline = RMW_QOS_DEADLINE_DEFAULT;
    custom_qos_profile.lifespan = RMW_QOS_LIFESPAN_DEFAULT;
    custom_qos_profile.liveliness = RMW_QOS_POLICY_LIVELINESS_SYSTEM_DEFAULT;
    custom_qos_profile.liveliness_lease_duration =
        RMW_QOS_LIVELINESS_LEASE_DURATION_DEFAULT;
    custom_qos_profile.avoid_ros_namespace_conventions = false;

    // Convert rmw_qos_profile_t to rclcpp::QoS
    auto qos =
        rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::QoSInitialization::from_rmw(custom_qos_profile));

    rectifLeftImagePub = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
        "left/image_rect", qos);

I get time from the DepthAI library because ROS 2 time will change a lot in while loops. I give left and right images and info topics the same time in header before publishing.
The following is the code for getting the time:
 rclcpp::Time frame_time(
            leftFrame->getTimestamp().time_since_epoch().count());

I publish the images next to each other in lines of code so we can rule out some extra processing reasons.
Now, the following are the messages I get when I run SLAM using this ROS 2 driver:
RTABMAP:
[stereo_odometry-1] [WARN] [1721859987.724759669] [rtabmap.stereo_odometry]: The time difference between left and right frames is high (diff=0.033334s, left=26443.584935s, right=26443.551602s). If your left and right cameras are hardware synchronized, use approx_sync:=false. Otherwise, you may want to set approx_sync_max_interval lower than 0.01s to reject spurious bad synchronizations.
[rtabmap_viz-3] [WARN] [1721859988.130394440] [rtabmap.rtabmap_viz]: rtabmap_viz: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ ros2 topic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). If topics are not published at the same rate, you could increase "sync_queue_size" and/or "topic_queue_size" parameters (current=10 and 1 respectively).

Isaac cuVSLAM:
[component_container-1] [WARN] [1721857101.364438853] [visual_slam_node]: Delta between current and previous frame [66.667292 ms] is above threshold [40.000000 ms]
[component_container-1] [WARN] [1721857102.246187855] [visual_slam_node]: Delta between current and previous frame [166.666523 ms] is above threshold [40.000000 ms]
[component_container-1] [WARN] [1721857103.205986818] [visual_slam_node]: Delta between current and previous frame [66.666345 ms] is above threshold [40.000000 ms]
[component_container-1] [WARN] [1721857104.360939501] [visual_slam_node]: Delta between current and previous frame [66.667270 ms] is above threshold [40.000000 ms]

Can someone please help me synchronize the left and right rectified pairs or change some settings so that I don't receive these messages from SLAM algorithms?
